# Excel direct edit mode vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to prevent users from directly typing into a cell that is selected, I have prevented the cell from going into edit mode when double clicked. However, I still need to prevent them from typing into the cell when it's selected, to do this I would like to disable direct edit mode using VBA. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Do you want the users to be able to change the cell by selecting it and typing a new entry but not by double clicking and editing whatever is already there?

Answer (score 0):

You can protect cells with the build-in function, for example like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyProtect()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rn As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Unprotect sheet.
sh.Unprotect

'Unlock all cells on the sheet.
sh.Cells.Locked = False

'Lock the chosen cell.
Set rn = sh.Range("A1")
rn.Locked = True

'Protect the worksheet.
sh.Protect
'Or protect with password.
'sh.Protect Password:="test"

End Sub
```